# How can I build an effective rotary composter?

Tags: composting, construction, product-design

I have a fenced in back yard and I am thinking about building a rotary composter.  What is a good and proven design?

(I would like it to be big enough for a 4 person house)

Comment: How big do you need it to be?  Is any volume sufficient?

Comment: @Nate I would like it to be big enough for a 4 person house.

Comment: I have a store-bought rotating drum, sized about 100L I think, and I find that it's very heavy to turn even when not particularly full. The stickier the material, the further around it needs to be turned before the material turns over, and the heavier it feels. My conclusion was that it wasn't money well spent, and it certainly wouldn't be adequate for all your composting needs. Some kind of gearing would probably be necessary for anything larger.

Comment: .. you mean a bearing? as for gearing, a long lever that can be aplied at different angels should be enough, no?

Comment: watching:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEQKPOT0sSY

Answer (score 2):

These look suitable:

- http://www.wikihow.com/Build-a-Tumbling-Composter
- http://www.instructables.com/id/compost-bin

If one is insufficient, you can always add another.